# android intent null pointer exception

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent, nullpointerexception

Im getting a Null Pointer Exception error in my AreaURL class. Everything was working fine until i added a Alert Dialog to my onCreate method and i know the error is with my intent due to the fact when i comment it out the action goes through. Here is my code for my AreaURL

```
public class AreaURL extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

Button button1;
private String petrolPriceURL = "http://www.petrolprices.com/feeds/averages.xml?search_type=town&search_value=glasgow";

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.userurldisplay);

    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
```

}

```
public void onClick(View v) {

new AlertDialog.Builder(Area.this)
.setTitle("Confirm")
.setMessage("Is this the XML feed you require?")
.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
        // continue
            TestMethod();
        }
    })
.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
        // do nothing
    }
 })
.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
 .show();
```

}

```
public void TestMethod(){
    EditText mEdit;
    EditText mEdit2;

    String newFirstString = petrolPriceURL.substring(0,59);
    String newSecondString = petrolPriceURL.substring(63,77);

    mEdit   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    mEdit.getText().toString();

    mEdit2   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    mEdit2.getText().toString();

    String newThirdString = newFirstString + mEdit.getText().toString();
    String newFourthString = newSecondString + mEdit2.getText().toString();
    String newFifthString = newThirdString + newFourthString;

    Intent intent=new Intent(this,PetrolPriceActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("URLString",newFifthString);
    startActivity(intent);
}

}
```

The part that triggers the Exception is my intent

```
Intent intent=new Intent(this,PetrolPriceActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("URLString",newFifthString);
    startActivity(intent);
}

}
```

Im new to working with Android so any help would be much appreciated.

edit: when i added this in order to check the URL is not null the application displays the correct string

```
   response = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    response.setText(newFifthString);
```

edit:logcat is

08-07 12:11:44.453: I/Choreographer(1257): Skipped 126 frames!
The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-07 12:11:46.313: I/Choreographer(1257): Skipped 131 frames!
The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-07 12:11:48.033: I/Choreographer(1257): Skipped 33 frames!
The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-07 12:11:51.753: D/dalvikvm(1257): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 137K, 6% free 3938K/4152K, paused 146ms, total 146ms
08-07 12:11:52.003: D/AndroidRuntime(1257): Shutting down VM
08-07 12:11:52.003: W/dalvikvm(1257): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3a96ba8)
08-07 12:11:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1257): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-07 12:11:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1257): Process: org.me.myandroidstuff, PID: 1257
08-07 12:11:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1257): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.me.myandroidstuff/org.me.myandroidstuff.PetrolPriceActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-07 12:11:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1257):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
08-07 12:11:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1257):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
08-07 12:11:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1257):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
08-07 12:11:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1257):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
08-07 12:11:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1257):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-07 12:11:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1257):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-07 12:11:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1257):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
08-07 12:11:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1257):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-07 12:11:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1257):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-07 12:11:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1257):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
08-07 12:11:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1257):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
08-07 12:11:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1257):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-07 12:11:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1257): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-07 12:11:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1257):     at org.me.myandroidstuff.PetrolPriceActivity.onCreate(PetrolPriceActivity.java:53)
08-07 12:11:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1257):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
08-07 12:11:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1257):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
08-07 12:11:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1257):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
08-07 12:11:52.063: E/AndroidRuntime(1257):     ... 11 more

my xml layout

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:text="@string/thank_you" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:background="#CCCCCC"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
    android:background="#CCCCCC"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="214dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/OK" />
```

this my PetrolPriceActivity class

```
package org.me.myandroidstuff;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class PetrolPriceActivity extends Activity 
{
private TextView response;
private TextView errorText;
private String result;
private String petrolPriceURL;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras!=null){
        petrolPriceURL =extras.getString("URLString");

    }
    // Get the TextView object on which to display the results
    response = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title);
    try
    {
        // Get the data from the RSS stream as a string
        result =  petrolPriceString(petrolPriceURL);

        // Do some processing of the data to get the individual parts of the RSS stream
        // At some point put this processing into a separate thread of execution
        // Display the string in the TextView object just to demonstrate this capability
        // This will need to be removed at some point
        response.setText(result);
    }
    catch(IOException ae)
    {
        // Handle error
        response.setText("Error");
        // Add error info to log for diagnostics
        errorText.setText(ae.toString());
    } 

}

// End of onCreate

// Method to handle the reading of the data from the RSS stream
private static String petrolPriceString(String urlString)throws IOException
{
    String result = "";
    InputStream anInStream = null;
    int response = -1;
    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

    // Check that the connection can be opened
    if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))
            throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");
    try
    {
        // Open connection
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
        httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        httpConn.connect();
        response = httpConn.getResponseCode();
        // Check that connection is Ok
        if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
        {
            // Connection is OK so open a reader 
            anInStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader in= new InputStreamReader(anInStream);
            BufferedReader bin= new BufferedReader(in);

            // Read in the data from the RSS stream
            String line = new String();
            while (( (line = bin.readLine())) != null)
            {
                result = result + "\n" + line;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
            throw new IOException("Error connecting");
    }

    // Return result as a string for further processing
    return result;
}
// End of petrolPriceString
// End of Activity class
}
```

Comment: your this inside alert dialog and onclick method should be AreaURL.this

Comment: no that hasn't worked the exception still occurs when i click the button

Comment: check your URL I think it returns Null!

Comment: thats me edited the code with AreaURL.this. Zafer do you mean the newFifthString? when i add a textview to show whats in the string it comes up the correct URL

Comment: what's is your logcat?

Comment: Can you post the layout?

Comment: I think that the problem is the button, maybe your button in your layour has another name.

Comment: not sure how to edit the logcat is its more readable sorry. ill post my layout

Comment: Checking your log, I can see the problem is in the PetrolPriceActivity, so, can you post the code from that activity, you have a problem with a variable in the onCreate() method.

Comment: ill post PetrolPriceActivity

Comment: Check if response = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title), really exists in your layout, and his name in your xml is the same.

Comment: yes it does. i have my list.xml and title is the id of that textview

Comment: If is possible, post the completely the PetrolPriceActivity class, including the imports an package name.

Comment: <TextView  
android:id="@+id/title"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textColor="#00FFFF"
android:textSize="16sp"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:paddingTop="6dip"
android:paddingBottom="2dip" />

Comment: what is on line 53 on your PetrolPriceAcrivity class?

Comment: thats me done that. Also i noticed that before i added the dialog the intent worked if that helps

Comment: Check my answer, if not works tell me.

Comment: errorText.setText(ae.toString()); - this guardian06

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is

```
errorText.setText(ae.toString());
```

You are not initializing that variable.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list);
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////Solution
    errorText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.yourTextView);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras!=null){
        petrolPriceURL =extras.getString("URLString");

    }
    // Get the TextView object on which to display the results
    response = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title);
    try
    {
        // Get the data from the RSS stream as a string
        result =  petrolPriceString(petrolPriceURL);

        // Do some processing of the data to get the individual parts of the RSS stream
        // At some point put this processing into a separate thread of execution
        // Display the string in the TextView object just to demonstrate this capability
        // This will need to be removed at some point
        response.setText(result);
    }
    catch(IOException ae)
    {
        // Handle error
        response.setText("Error");
        // Add error info to log for diagnostics
        errorText.setText(ae.toString()); //////////This variable is not intialized.
    }
```

}

Comment: Is the same thing like response = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title);

Comment: sorry ehh what would my Id be? response is where the string goes hence why my title textView holds the data recieved by the URL

Comment: I think that in your xml layout from the PetrolPriceActivity, you have two edittext, the first is the title, check your xml, what Id are using when declaring the EditText in your layout for the errorText.

Comment: okay changing my id to title has fixed the bug but however rather than show my URL i now have a error shown instead. Also my xml layout is different from the layout i posted. i use list.xml for PetrolPriceActivity and testdisplay.xml for my URLArea

Comment: well, either add another textView to your layout and only show it when it's needed or append the errorText to response

Comment: Why appear the error in the Edittext?, Is because maybe you are doing this errorText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title), so whe you executing the code, that code entry to catch(), so en the catch you have errorText.setText(ae.toString()).

Comment: ok my issue is this. Firstly my code should be showing the URL as an XML feed however it is now showing me the error code so clearly my code hasnt worked as im getting the error. Im trying to have it so when i click the okay button it then displays my XML feed based on the URL. My exeption means my connection through my URL failed

Comment: Ok, Do you try putting two Edittext in your XML One for your title, and another for the Error?

Comment: <TextView  
android:id="@+id/title"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textColor="#00FFFF"
android:textSize="16sp"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:paddingTop="6dip"
android:paddingBottom="2dip" />



<TextView  
android:id="@+id/error"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textColor="#ffff"
android:paddingBottom="2dip">
</TextView>

</LinearLayout>

Comment: And you try doing (TextView)findViewById(R.id.error)?

Comment: So, the error message is showing in the Error EditText, and the title EditText what is showing?

Comment: it isnt showing because the exception is being triggered. Instead of title i get error. it must mean that my extras is null but when i checked it in the application i get the URL so i dont understand

Comment: so, I think that the error has to be in petrolPriceString(petrolPriceURL);

Comment: ill check what lies in result then. How do i use log. to then see the contents of result in the logcat?

Comment: Log.d("RETURN", result);

Comment: Some thing in your method petrolPriceString is crashing, so for that reason is entering in the catch().

Comment: Well, just relax, and check your method, so, can you evaluate my first answer?. Regards.

Comment: sorry what do u mean by evaluate ur answer?

Comment: He means if he answered your original problem, the polite thing to do is upvote his answer and "Accept" it.

Comment: ahhh of course thanks very much for your help. Wont let me upvote but i have accepted it